# Hydration error after adding button in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Im getting a hydration error after i added a button in my section.
Here is the error that I got :

```
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
```

Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching form in section.

I tried getting the button out of the form but that didn't work

Here is the code of the whole component:

```
const Form = ({ type, post, setPost, submitting, handleSubmit }) => {
  return (
    <section className="w-full max-w-full flex-col flex-start">
      <h1 className="head_text text-left">
        <span className="blue_gradient">{type} Post</span>
      </h1>
      <p className="desc text-left max-w-md">{type} and share amzing prompts</p>
      <form
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        className="mt-10 w-full max-w-2xl flex flex-col gap-7 glassmorphism"
      >
        <label>
          <span className="font-satoshi font-semibold text-base text-gray-700">
            Your AI Prompt
          </span>
          <textarea
            value={post.prompt}
            onChange={(e) =>
              setPost({
                ...post,
                prompt: e.target.value,
              })
            }
            placeholder="Write your prompt here..."
            required
            className="form_textarea"
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          <span className="font-satoshi font-semibold text-base text-gray-700">
            Tag
          </span>
          <input
            value={post.tag}
            onChange={(e) =>
              setPost({
                ...post,
                tag: e.target.value,
              })
            }
            placeholder="#tag"
            required
            className="form_input"
          />
        </label>
        <div className="flex-end mx-3 mb-5 gap-4">
          <Link href="/" className="text-gray-500 text-sm">
            Cancel
          </Link>
          {/* Hydration Error */}
          <button
            type="submit"
            disabled={submitting}
            className="px-5 py-1.5 text-sm bg-primary-orange rounded-full text-white"
          >
            {submitting ? `${type}ing...` : type}
          </button>
          {/* Hydration Error */}
        </div>
      </form>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

the button tag at the bottom is causing the hydration error.

i called this component here:

```
const CreatePrompt = () => {
  const [submitting, setSubmitting] = useState(false);
  const [post, setPost] = useState({
    prompt: "",
    tag: "",
  });

  const createPrompt = async (e) => {};
  return (
    <Form
      type="create"
      post={post}
      setPost={setPost}
      submitting={submitting}
      handleSubmit={createPrompt}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything invalid with your HTML semantics, so you'd have to share where those values come from that use use inside your JSX, like `{type}` , `{submitting}` and so on

Comment: I have duplicated your example above and do not receive a hydration error, can you provide the rest of the component? Also if there is a `useEffect` somewhere inside the component that is most likely the cause for the error.

Comment: I don't think {type} and {submitting} are the issue because I deleted them and still got the error

Comment: Can you please add all of the code for this component,  not just the returned JSX

Comment: Normally Hydration error is caused by invalid html, like a script inside div or similar. Fixing invalid html tags may fix that.

Comment: i edited the post for the full code